# Why doesn't my Perl map return anything?

Tags: perl, dictionary

When I am running the following statement:

```
@filtered = map {s/&nbsp;//g} @outdata;
```

it is returning an empty list instead of the filtered list that I expected.  What I am trying to do is remove every occurrence of `&nbsp;` from an array of string (which is an XML file).

Obviously, I am not understanding something.  Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this might be, and why this isn't working for me as is?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458454/why-is-the-list-my-perl-map-returns-just-1s/1461242#1461242, and it has the same answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
@filtered = map {s/&nbsp;//g; $_} @outdata;
```

The problem is the s operator in perl modifies $_ but actually returns the number of changes it made. So, the extra $_ at the end causes perl to return the modified string for each element of @outdata.

Comment: I'm not feeling mean enough to downvote, but this is a Bad Idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103/why-doesnt-my-perl-map-return-anything/21792#21792 is a much better answer.

Comment: With [Perl 5.14's non-destructive substitution](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/), you can do this like `@filtered = map { s/&nbsp;//gr } @outdata` without affecting `@outdata`.

Answer (score 15):

Note that map is going to modify your source array as well. So you could either do:

```
map {s/&nbsp;//g} @outdata;
```

and skip the @filtered variable altogether, or if you need to retain the originals,

```
@filtered = @outdata;
map {s/&nbsp;//g} @filtered;
```

Although, in that case, it might be more readable to use foreach:

```
s/&nbsp;//g foreach @filtered;
```

Comment: `map` in void context is generally considered poor form and doesn't say anything over `for @filtered { ... }`.

Answer (score 9):

Greg's answer has the problem that it will modify the original array as the $_ are passed aliased. You need:

```
@filtered = map { (my $new = $_) =~ s/&nbsp;//g; $new} @outdata;
```

Answer (score 6):

To follow up on Tithonium's point, this will also do the trick:

```
@filtered = map {local $_=$_; s/&nbsp;//g; $_} @outdata;
```

The "local" ensures you're working on a copy, not the original.

Answer (score 5):

In perl 5.14 you could use the */r* regex modifier to [make non-destructive substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions).

```
@filtered = map {s/&nbsp;//gr} @outdata;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use Algorithm::Loops "Filter";
@filtered = Filter { s/&nbsp;//g } @outdata;
```

Answer (score 3):

As a counterpoint to Greg's answer, you could misuse grep:

```
@filtered = grep {s/&nbsp;//g; 1} @outdata;
```

**Don't do this.**