# Why is the list my Perl map returns just 1's?

Tags: perl, dictionary

The code I wrote is as below :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @input = ( "a.txt" , "b.txt" , "c.txt" ) ;
my @output = map { $_ =~ s/\..*$// } @input ;

print @output ;
```

My intention is to let the file name without the extension stored in the array `@output`. 
but instead it stores the value returned by `s///` rather than the changed file name in `@output`, so the result looks like

```
1
1
1
```

so what is the correct way to use `map` under this situation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, first off, you probably meant to have `$_ =~ s/\..*$//` — note the missing `s` in your example. Also, you probably mean `map` not `grep`.

Second, that doesn't do what you want. That actually modifies `@input`! Inside `grep` (and `map`, and several other places), `$_` is actually aliased to each value. So you're actually changing the value.

Also note that pattern match does not return the matched value; it returns true (if there is a match) or false (if there isn't). That's all the 1's you're seeing.

Instead, do something like this:

```
my @output = map {
    (my $foo = $_) =~ s/\..*$//;
    $foo;
} @input ;
```

The first copies `$_` to `$foo`, and then modifies `$foo`. Then, it returns the modified value (stored in `$foo`). You can't use `return $foo`, because its a block, not a subroutine.

Comment: @derobert: the missing 's' is a edit error, I've fix it . and I've tested your solution and it works !

Comment: List::MoreUtils http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils offers `apply` which is perfect for this sort of thing.  It works like a `map`, but will not alter the values in the array argument.  `use List::MoreUtils 'apply'; my @output = apply { s/\..*$// } @input;`

Comment: daotoad: Good point, apply is definitely a good choice here, too.

Answer (score 25):

Out of all of those answers, no one simply said that `map` returns the result of the last evaluated expression. Whatever you do last is the thing (or things) `map` returns. It's just like a subroutine or `do` returning the result of their last evaluated expression.

Perl v5.14 adds the non-destructive substitution, which I write about in [Use the /r substitution flag to work on a copy](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/). Instead of returning the number of replacements, it returns the modified copy. Use the `/r` flag:

```
my @output = map { s/\..*$//r } @input;
```

Note that you don't need to use the `$_` with the binding operator since that's the default topic.

Answer (score 7):

The problem of `$_` aliasing the list's values was already discussed.

But what's more: Your question's title clearly says "map", but your code uses grep, although it looks like it really should use map.

`grep` will evaluate each element in the list you provide as a second argument. And in list context it will return a list consisting of those elements of the original list for which your expression returned true.

`map` on the other hand uses the expression or block argument to transform the elements of the list argument returning a new list consisting of the transformed arguments of the original.

Thus your problem could be solved with code like this:

```
@output = map { m/(.+)\.[^\.]+/ ? $1 : $_ } @input;
```

This will match the part of the file name that is not an extension and return it as a result of the evaluation or return the original name if there is no extension.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the 's' for substitution.

```
$_ =~ /\..*$//
```

should be

```
$_ =~ s/\..*$//
```

Also you might be better off to use `s/\.[^\.]*$//` as your regular expression to make sure you just remove the extension even when the filename contains a '.' (dot) character.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, s/// returns the number of substitutions performed, and map returns the last expression evaluated from each iteration, so your map returns all 1's. One way to accomplish what you want is:

```
s/\..*$// for my @output = @input;
```

Another way is to use Filter from [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Loops/)

Comment: it's the little details that get you in Perl, a good reason to, unless you think you fully understand the language, should stick to modules when things get dicey.

Answer (score 1):

[derobert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458454/perl-map-function-problem/1458476#1458476) shows you a correct way of mapping `@input` to `@output`.

I would, however, recommend using [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

my @input = qw( a.1.txt b.txt c.txt );
my @output = map { scalar fileparse($_, qr/\.[^.]*/) } @input ;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@output;
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Temp> h
$VAR1 = [
          'a.1',
          'b',
          'c'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem: both [the `s/../.../` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer) and [Perl's `map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) are imperative, expecting you to want to modify each input item; Perl doesn't in fact have a builtin for the functional `map` that yields its results without modifying the input.

When using `s`, an option is to append the `r` modifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @input = ( "a.txt" , "b.txt" , "c.txt" ) ;
my @output = map { s/\..*$//r } @input ;

print join(' ', @output), "\n";
```

The general solution (suggested by derobert) is to use [List::MoreUtils::apply](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#apply):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use List::MoreUtils qw(apply);

my @input = ( "a.txt" , "b.txt" , "c.txt" ) ;
my @output = apply { s/\..*$// } @input ;

print join(' ', @output), "\n";
```

or copy its definition into your code:

```
sub apply (&@) {
    my $action = shift;
    &$action foreach my @values = @_;
    wantarray ? @values : $values[-1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code sample is missing an `s` in the match operator.  Other than that, it worked fine for me:

```
$, = "\n";
my @input = ( "a.txt" , "b.txt" , "c.txt" );
my @output = grep { $_ =~ s/\..*$// } @input;
print @output;
```

Output is:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Do a `print @input` and note how your code mangles `@input`, which is unexpected and very likely unwanted.