# separating array elements every 4 characters in array

Tags: perl

I have an array like this

```
my @array=(0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020)
```

I want to insert comma for each of the 4 character what i mean here is

```
my @array=(0x0B,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x02)
```

#### My Perl code

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @hex_array;
# Name of the input file
my $input_filename = 'input.txt';

# Open the file
open my $input_fh, "<", $input_filename or die $!;

# Name of the output file
my $outut_filename = 'output.txt';

# Open the file
open my $output_fh, "<", $output_filename or die $!;

# reading input file by line by line.
while (<input_fh>)
{
    # here i am extracting all hex value
    while ($_ =~ m/(0x(\d+)(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi)
    {
        push @hex_array, $1; #push the element
    } # end of second while loop
} # end of first while loop

print @hex_array;
```

#### first approach

```
unpack("(A2)*", $hex_array);
print {$output_fh} join("U, ", @hex_array);
```

#### second approach

```
foreach my $element (@hex_array)
{
   if (length $element eq 4)
   {
       #print @hex_array;
       print {$output_fh} join("U, ", @hex_array);
   }
}
```

but both approaches did not work. What would be an appropriate solution?

Comment: This is very unclear. Are those `my@array` lines literal content of your file? Are you trying to programmatically change a piece of source code? Are both approaches in the same program, or did you try each of them individually?

Comment: I should be my @array, I was trying both the approaches on same program and also tried each of them individually .

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020"

Comment: @choroba I think that first code block is the content of `DATA`. But there's a `0` too much at the end.

Comment: considering your history of similar questions with no accepted answers, it seems hard to help you

Comment: You open `$output_fh` in read mode `"<"` and then print to it.

Comment: The code you show won't even compile. Neither `$output_filename` nor `input_fh` exist. Did you just add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your program before you posted it so that you wouldn't get told off?

Comment: yes $output_fh  will be write mode .just I have given some information that what I want to do

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
my @array = ("0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020");
my @outarray = map { (my $vars = $_) =~ s/\w{4}/$&\,/g; $vars; } @array ;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @outarray;
```

[Thanks to @derobert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458454/why-is-the-list-my-perl-map-returns-just-1s)

Comment: I have tried your approach with adding more array elements I got output looks like :$VAR1 = '0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020x000x000x0A0x000x000x000x040x000x000x040x050x000x001f0x001f0x007f0x000x000x002b0x007f';

Comment: `print Dumper @outarray;`

Comment: And also Junk characters found in your more elements added in array.

Comment: @ssr1012, If you examine the code, you'll see they actually have `my @hex_array = ( '0x0B', '0x0C', '0x4A', '0x00', '0x01', '0x00', '0x00', '0x02' );`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for exactly your example, if that array assignment is its own line and is not multi-line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    # find and grab the chunk of hex values inside of the array assignment
    ( my $match ) = $line =~ m/\(((?:0x[0-9A-F]{2})+)\)/;

    next unless $match;

    # make a copy that we will change
    my $replaced = $match;

    # add a comma every four until the last one
    # and insert comma
    $replaced =~ s/(....)(?!$)/$1,/g;

    # but the replacement back into the current line
    $line =~ s/\Q$match\E/$replaced/;

    print $line;
}

__DATA__
my@array=(0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x02)
```

As soon as the initial pattern for `$line` doesn't match, it will break apart. Also note that you have an additional `0` at the end of your long string of hex numbers. My code only works if you fix that.

Output:

```
my@array=(0x0B,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x02)
```

Comment: sorry I have not explained my requirement properly.The input my @array that is actually my hex_array dump that I have collected from my code now I want to separate hex_array element for each of 4 character by comma.

Comment: @abhi I have no idea what you are talking about. Please go back, edit your question and clearly explain, with properly indented code. We're all guessing here.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have

```
my @hex_array = ( 0x0B0x0C0x4A0x000x010x000x000x020 );
```

For starters, that doesn't even compile. What you actually have is the following:

```
my @hex_array = ( '0x0B', '0x0C', '0x4A', '0x00', '0x01', '0x00', '0x00', '0x02' );
```

To get

```
my @num_array = ( 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 );
```

simply change

```
push @hex_array, $1;
```

to

```
push @num_array, hex($1);
```